# runOnUiThread inside a View

Tags: java, android, view

I'm making a custom `ImageView` . One of the methods is to load an image from a URL. And I want to retrieve the Bitmap in a Thread and load the bitmap in the UI thread.

How can I make a `runOnUIThread()` call for painting the bitmap?

Is there some kind of built in function? Or should I create a `Handler` in the constructor and use it for running runnables in the UI thread?

Comment: go with Handler.  runOnUIThread is a method of Activity if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Download the Image via `AsyncTask` and set to your view in its **onPostExecute** method

OR

From a separate image downloading thread use the **post** method of `View` which will always run its `Runnable` on *UI-thread*:

```
yourImageView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // set the downloaded image here

    }
});
```

Comment: Must read the link posted by cyrilchampier in comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     final Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromURL(myStation.getStation().imageURL);
     ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         icon.setImageBitmap(bm);
       }
     });
   }
 }).start();
```

This will work outside of an activity, like in a ListAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that extends from AsyncTask. Pass the ImageView in the constructor. In the doInBackground method, download the image. In the postExecute method, set the image to the ImageView.