# Start a new CountDownTimer inside a run method

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, game-loop, thread-synchronization

I am new to android development, and I am trying to create a little game. I have my first `CountDownTimer` created by the constructor in my `GameView` subclass of `SurfaceView`.

What I should do in order to pass on the next level, is call the `cancel()` of the `CountDownTimer class`, readapting all the elements for a next level and create a new `CountDownTimer`again. I am doing this in the `run()` of my `GameView` class that implements `Runnable`.

I've been reading things through online, but most of the solution are using `Activities`, as I said, I am working in a subclass of `SurfaceView`.

This is the error I am receiving

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
              Process: com.example.lucadigiammarino.biogame, PID: 3569
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                  at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:114)
                  at android.os.CountDownTimer.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:114)
                  at com.example.lucadigiammarino.biogame.GameCountDownTimer.<init>(GameCountDownTimer.java:0)
                  at com.example.lucadigiammarino.biogame.GameView.startTimer(GameView.java:135)
                  at com.example.lucadigiammarino.biogame.GameView.run(GameView.java:306)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: You try to run some functions dealing with the UI not in main thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086129/runonuithread-inside-a-view

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Roman I manage to solve my problem, the answer is here for a more detailed explanation  ---> [runOnUiThread inside a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086129/runonuithread-inside-a-view)

What I've done I just created a different `Thread` inside my `run()` using `post()`. I repeat that I am in a subclass of `SurfaceView`.

```
post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myTimer.cancel;
        startTimer() //creates a new timer
    }
});
```

Hope it can be helpful for someone else in the future!